# Connection with SQL Server and Oracle from .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, vb.net-2010

From ASP.NET, I need to connect to SQL Server database and Oracle database.

From .NET, I can connect direct to SQL Server database (SqlClient.SqlConnection), and can connect via ODBC. The same with Oracle, can connect via (OracleClient) as well as ODBC.

My question is: 
Which is the best practice to connect to SQL Server database or Oracle database, via ODBC or direct, and what is performance effect?

Comment: I wouldnt use OBDC to connect to oracle. I would use oracles odp.net dll which will make your life a whole lot easier. Microsoft already has a driver for sql server so that should just be plug and play. The  performance question is a loaded question which has many variables to take into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to use a managed provider from managed code. That would be `SqlClient` for SQL Server and [ODP.NET](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) for Oracle. Both implement the ADO.NET IDb* interfaces if you need shared code for both.